# Nginx 502 bad getaway in Django register and login page

Tags: python, django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

I've deployed a Django app with **nginx** and **gunicorn**. It's works fine except it's login form and register form.
When I submit either of forms I get "502 bad gateway" error message.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/config**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name croyal.net;
    server_name www.croyal.net;


    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Could anybody give me a clue so that I can find the root of the issue?

Comment: If your site is working except for login/register, then it probably isn’t the nginx conf.  Look at the login views, paths, templates.

Comment: can I contact to you for helping me? @raphael